# Drupal: How should I implement hook_schema, then to use Date module's date_select in my form

Tags: date, drupal-6, content-type

I am creating new node type in my drupal module. It is the first time I want to create new node type without CCK `:)`

Which data type should I use in `hook_schema`, then to use `date_select` field in `hook_form`?

```
function mymodule_schema() {
  $schema['mymodule']['call_time'] = array(
    'type'          => 'datetime', // which data type should I use?
    'not null'      => TRUE,
  );
}

function mymodule_form(&$node, $form_state) {
  $form['call_time'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_select', 
    // ... other options
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a little late...

Can't you really use `datetime` as in your example?

At least, according to Drupal documentation: http://drupal.org/node/159605

Comment: Yes, I did use `datetime`. I hadn't been sure about that when I asked the question. Thanks for answer `:)`

Answer (score 0):

drupal core does not include "datetime".
you need to use the "[date](http://drupal.org/project/date)"-module.